# How to use Socks4 with http client

Tags: go

This is my current solution for using a Socks5. Is there any solution for getting a Socks4 to work? I want to send a Get request with a Socks4.

```golang
proxyUrl, err := url.Parse("socks5://123.123.123.123:9999")
myClient := &http.Client{Transport: &http.Transport{Proxy: http.ProxyURL(proxyUrl)}}
```

Answer (score 1):

`net/http/transport` only supports `http`, `https` or `socks5` proxies out of the box (quoting documentation):

> The proxy type is determined by the URL scheme. "http", "https", and "socks5" are supported. If the scheme is empty, "http" is assumed.

To work with `socks4` or `socks4a` proxies you can use an existing library, for example [h12.io/socks](https://godoc.org/h12.io/socks) and then pass `socks4` dial to `Transport` like this:

```golang
import "h12.io/socks"
```

```golang
dial := socks.Dial("socks4://123.123.123.123:9999")
transp := &http.Transport{Dial: dial}
myClient := &http.Client{Transport: transp}
```